# How does data-storage work in html5?

Tags: html

How does data-storage work in html5? I am curious about data-storage some asked me about it also while interview so please can you tell me?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 1):

There is session storage and local storage, but you're probably looking for local storage which is a key-value map providing string storage for the domain and is accessible via the `localStorage` object in javascript. There are plenty of resources that go into great depth on the topic, but here are two starters:

https://w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

https://smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: The Web SQL API was not mentioned because it's not officially part of the html5 spec and it's deprecated